# Is it possible to trigger an ng-repeat inside a JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, for-loop, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a tooltip that is formatted in a table structure. That tooltip is in a js file and shown below:

JS FILE:

```
        scope.options.chart.tooltip =  {    
                        contentGenerator: function (e) {
                            var series = e.series[0];
                            if (series.value === null) {return;}

                            var header =
                                "<thead>" +
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                                "<td class='key'>" + series.key + " CCIRs:</td>" +
                                "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>";

                            var rows =
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='key'><strong>" + <INSERT HERE> + "</strong></td>" +
                                "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute1 + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>" 

                            return "<table>" +
                                header +
                                "<tbody>" +
                                rows +
                                "</tbody>" +
                                "</table>";
                        }
                    }
```

Where it says "INSERT HERE", I'd struggling to determine how to print each value of an array so that the tooltip will show a new row per each index item.

I have tried injecting ng-repeat as one viable solution:

```
var rows =
        "<tr ng-repeat='x in myArray'>" +
        "<td class='key'><strong>" + {{x.propName}} + "</strong></td>"
```

But that returns a syntax error.

Another solution I have tried is doing a simple 'for' loop of the object I'd like printed in the tooltip, but then Im stuck figuring out how to take that Array and print each item dynamically for each table row yet again:

```
var myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ccirdata.length; i++) {
                if (ccirdata[i].catType === 'I') {      
                    myArray.push(ccirdata[i].propName);

                }
            }
```

I have to somehow figure out how to print each indexed item of myArray in this JS file, but I'm having trouble here! Please help!

EDIT: Here is the whole directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
/* jshint quotmark: false */

angular
    .module('webApp')
    .directive('ccirSummary', ccirSummary);

ccirSummary.$inject = ['$window', 'Accessibility', 'Tools', 'ccirSummaryChartConfig', '$timeout'];
function ccirSummary($window, Accessibility, Tools, ccirSummaryChartConfig, $timeout)
{
    var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        vm: '='
    },
    link: ccirSummaryLink,
    templateUrl: 'scripts/tiles/ccirSummary/views/ccirSummary.html'
};
return directive;

function ccirSummaryLink(scope, element /*, attrs*/)
{
    $timeout(function() {     

     console.log(Object.keys(scope.vm)); 
     var ccirSummaryChartInfo = scope.vm;
     var ccirdata = ccirSummaryChartInfo.ccirdata;

    scope.options = ccirSummaryChartConfig.getChartConfig();  
    console.log(ccirdata);

    var myArray = [];


            for (var i = 0; i < ccirdata.length; i++) {
                if (ccirdata[i].catType === 'I') {      
                    myArray.push(ccirdata[i].propName);
                }
            }


    scope.options.chart.tooltip =  {    
                        contentGenerator: function (e) {
                            var series = e.series[0];
                            if (series.value === null) {return;}

                            var header =
                                "<thead>" +
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                                "<td class='key'>" + series.key + " CCIRs:</td>" +
                                "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>";

                            var rows =
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<td class='key'><strong>" + INSERT HERE + "</strong></td>" +
                                "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute1 + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>" 

                            return "<table>" +
                                header +
                                "<tbody>" +
                                rows +
                                "</tbody>" +
                                "</table>";
                        }
                    }

    scope.data = [
                {
                    key: 'Category I',
                    y: ccirSummaryChartInfo.ccirCategoryIncidentI,
                    MyAttribute1:'DLA Avn ... CAT I',

                },
                {
                    key: 'Category II',
                    y: ccirSummaryChartInfo.ccirCategoryIncidentII,
                    MyAttribute1:cat1CatNum,

                },
                {
                    key: 'Category III',
                    y: ccirSummaryChartInfo.ccirCategoryIncidentIII,
                    MyAttribute1:'DLA Avn ... CAT III',

                },
            ];          

    var lastUpdatedDateTime;
    var forceUpdate = false;
    scope.$watch('vm.ccirdata' , function (newValue)
    {

    });

    }, 500);

    var tooltip = Tools.buildTooltip ({
        base: element,
        tipText: getccirHintText
    });


        }    
    }
})();
```

Comment: As previously mentioned to you `js file` is irrelevant...it's the component type in that js file that matters. All of this should be done with directives. You keep posting about this tooltip in numerous questions but never showing enough code for anyone to see how you re trying to implement it. Are you even doing this in directive?

Comment: sorry, I hope this helps, I have included the directive